# GRID: Números periódico

Tags: css-grid-layout

Mi duda nace de: Qué pasa con el espacio restante del resultado de crear 3 filas con
"displey: grid" en un contenedor con un height de 100px?

El problema de esto es que se crean 3 números periódicos de "33,333...px" para darle el height a cada fila.

¿Cómo resuelve CSS GRID esto? En toda la documentación que encontré me explica siempre lo mismo, que es la sintaxis lógica de GRID, pero no encontré ninguna que explique lo que acabo de comentar.

Si uno revisa el inspector WEB este arroja los valores correspondientes pero no muestra el decimal restante.

Si alguno sabe la lógica de Grid o sabe donde se encuentra la documentación correspondiente les estaría agradecido.

Edito para dejar un ejemplo:

CSS

```
.grid{
    display: grid;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    outline: 3px solid #000;
}

.grid__item{
    color: #fff;
}

.grid :nth-child(1){
    background: red;
}

.grid :nth-child(2){
    background: blue;
}

.grid :nth-child(3){
    background: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <section class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item">1</div>
        <div class="grid__item">2</div>
        <div class="grid__item">3</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) utiliza un algoritmo de reparto de espacio para distribuir el espacio restante entre las filas o columnas. En tu ejemplo, si se establece un `height` de 100px en un contenedor con 3 filas, cada fila recibiría un `height` de aproximadamente 33.333px, sin embargo debido a cómo funciona el algoritmo el espacio restante no se distribuye de manera exacta entre las filas, lo que queda en un decimal restante. El decimal restante no se muestra en la página porque los navegadores redondean automáticamente los valores de pixeles para evitar problemas de visualización.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100px;
}

.fila {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fila">Fila 1</div>
  <div class="fila">Fila 2</div>
  <div class="fila">Fila 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y el algoritmo del restante a que fila lo estaría distribuyendo? ¿O es que ese porcentaje lo elimina?.

Por lo que leí Grid a diferencia de Flex distribuye completamente.

Comment: Esto lo haría el navegador redondear a 33px para evitar problemas de visualización, comparto un enlace donde se explica cómo el algoritmo de reparto de espacio distribuye el espacio, específicamente en la sección "Distributing Space: the fr Unit" https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/

Comment: Ahora lo leo! Si esta ahí te marco el GreenCheck!